# Linux gcc: "proc.h" header missing. Where is the 'proc' struct defined?

Tags: c++, gcc, linux-kernel

I cannot find sys/proc.h in the gcc/g++ headers nor is there a "proc.h" in the linux headers folder. Which header defines this struct?

Comment: There's no `proc` in Linux. The closest thing is `task_struct` from `linux/sched.h`

Answer (score 1):

With `find` command

```
`find / -name "proc.h" 2>/dev/null`
```

find a lot of `proc.h` file under my `ubuntu` system, all are in `/usr/src/linux-headers-*`. But this is typical:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-44/arch/mn10300/proc-mn103e010/include/proc/proc.h
```

seems that this file is architecture dependent.

**UPDATE**:

I do not know if you are using MPI, but there is also a file `"/usr/lib/openmpi/include/openmpi/ompi/proc/proc.h"` under openMPI directory. Hope that helps.