‘proc_fops’ has an incomplete type ‘struct proc_ops’
I am trying to build a Linux kernel module, and in particular I have these files, all in the same folder:

syscalls.h/.c
user.h/.c
proc.h/.c
module.h/.c

I want to handle a configuration file into the /proc directory, so in the proc.h/.c files I have defined a driver to properly manage it:
proc.h
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>

extern struct proc_ops proc_fops;

ssize_t read_proc(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offp );
ssize_t write_proc(struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offp );

proc.c
#include "proc.h"

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5,6,0)
struct file_operations proc_fops = {
        .read = read_proc,
        .write = write_proc
};
#else
struct proc_ops proc_fops= {
        .proc_read =  read_proc,
        .proc_write =  write_proc
};
#endif

//...

ssize_t write_proc(struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offp ) {
    //...
}
ssize_t read_proc(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offp ) {
    //...
}

I wrote it into a separate "proc" code block because I want the file to be managed into both user.c and syscalls.c.
I have only implemented the user.c call, that is:
proc_create(PROCFILE, 0, NULL, proc_fops);

but I receive this error:
error: ‘proc_fops’ has an incomplete type ‘struct proc_ops’
  182 |     proc_create(PROCFILE, 0, NULL, proc_fops);
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~

and I cannot find where is the problem. Anyone have some clue? My kernel version (uname -r) is 5.4.0-192-generic.

Your #ifdef isn't correct; 5.4 (and 5.5) kernels still use struct file_operations, proc_ops is new to 5.6 and later. Given that "proc.h" is not a linux kernel provided include, and you provide an empty predeclaration there, this error would result. You should be getting the correct definition from proc_fs.h if the kernel rev you're building for has it.

Hi, thanks for your answer. Given the corrected #ifdef (now correct in the edited post), could you please explain further what you mean? I have #include <linux/proc_fs.h> in both proc.h and proc.c.

owner: THIS_MODULE What's this supposed to be? Yet another tiresome GNU extension or...?

Actually copypasted from other code :P but commenting it does not change the result (btw: now removed from the post)

I meant the comma part. It's invalid C syntax inside an initializer list. Apparently a GNU extension that went obsolete at some point back in the Cretaceous period.

Did you mean using the .read=read_proc notation instead of the read:read_proc one? In that case, changing it is for sure correct, but the problem still remains - EDITED IN POST

Looking at this code at Github it would appear the the struct definition is in neither proc.h nor proc.c but supposedly in some other header included by proc.h? #include <machine/proc.h> likely so maybe that one is missing then.

Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564550/linux-gcc-proc-h-header-missing-where-is-the-proc-struct-defined

Actually, proc.h and proc.c are files that I have defined, they do not exist in Linux Kernel. The only reference to the kernel is the import to proc_fs.h

Regardless, you must have a struct definition somewhere or else you'll get the "incomplete type" error message.

Isn't the extern struct proc_ops proc_fops; definition (proc.h) sufficient? (I mean, no, that's rhetorical, but why?

That's a forward declaration, not a definition. Hence incomplete type: you tell the compiler that "for now here's a struct, I'll tell you about the details later (in the same translation unit)"

Ok, so maybe the root cause of the problem is the lack of the definition. Could you please show an example? So that I can learn what to do and how to arrange things in order to solve the problem

proc_create(PROCFILE, 0, NULL, proc_fops); should be proc_create(PROCFILE, 0, NULL, &proc_fops);. (But proc_fops may have been declared with the wrong type by #include "proc.h", depending on the kernel version.)

That is really basic stuff... struct proc_ops { int proc_read ; int proc_write; /* ... */ }; Or whatever types these are supposed to have - I know nothing about what this code is supposed to do.

Notably struct proc_ops proc_fops= {         .proc_read =  read_proc,         .proc_write =  write_proc }; is just a variable declaration with an initializer list. It doesn't define the struct. Perhaps that's the source of the confusion.

Does "user.c" really need to know about proc_fops? Can't you just call proc_create from an interface function in "proc.c" (called from "user.c") and declare proc_fops, proc_read and proc_write static?

You need #include <linux/version.h> to define the LINUX_VERSION_CODE and KERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c) macros.

First of all, thank you for all your help, I am really appreciating your contributes.
I have an update: since my kernel version is <5.6.0, I have to use file_operations (imported from fs.h) instead of proc_ops (imported from proc_fs.h). So, when changing the declaration in proc.h from proc_ops to files_operations, it compiles without any error. I am still experimenting, but it could be a way to the solution (and it makes sense). Maybe I could use the same #if used in proc.c.

@IanAbbott thanks, already included (cut into the post for better readability)

It doesn't matter if proc_fops has an incomplete type in the call to proc_create as long as it has the correct incomplete type. You are just calling it wrong. It's expecting a pointer.

Forgot to mention: now the proc_create call is proc_create(PROCFILE, 0, NULL, &proc_fops); (now with &). Is this the pointer you refer to?

Solved (see answer). Thank you all for your support!

Solved, the problem was that the declaration in proc.h only contained the one for the proc_ops type, valid only for kernel version greater than 5.6.0. So, to complete compliance, I just changed it to:
proc.h
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5,6,0)
extern struct file_operations proc_fops;
#else
extern struct proc_ops proc_fops;
#endif

as well as correctly specify the pointer with & in:
proc.c
proc_create(PROCFILE, 0, NULL, &proc_fops);

